# Function in Python similar to egenmore's xtile() in Stata

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, stata, quantitative-finance

I am a Stata user and trying to replicate some code in Python.

More specifically, I want to create a new column which is called `port`.

In Stata my code to achieve the desired output is:

```
egen port = xtile(marketcap), nquantiles(10) by(date)
```

The `xtile()` function is part of the *community-contributed* package `egenmore`.

The above `egen` command is generating a variable called `port`, which returns a number from `1` to `10` for each observation that is dependent on the `marketcap` variable for each date.

The `xtile` function defines the variable we are utilising (`marketcap`), while the `nquantiles` option splits the data into terciles. The tickers whose marketcap is within the top tercile is coded as a `1`, second highest tercile as a `2` and so on, until the tickers whose marketcap is in the lowest tercile is coded as a `10`.
The result is a number in the `port` variable for each ticker on each date. This occurs as companies marketcap change between months and therefore will be situated in different terciles in different months.

I use monthly time-series data (10+ years), but have included data for 10 tickers over 2 months:

```
df.head()

date     ticker   return      marketcap
2004m1     A      0.02500   2.500117e+10
2004m1     B      0.04000   3.600111e+10
2004m1     C     -0.01500   4.900222e+11
2004m1     D     -0.02500   1.400134e+10
2004m1     E     -0.04000   3.200288e+10
2004m1     F     -0.01200   9.300110e+10
2004m1     G      0.03500   5.500512e+12
2004m1     H      0.04600   2.100177e+11
2004m1     I      0.00500   3.300155e+10
2004m1     J      0.00750   2.400999e+13
2004m1     K      0.02500   7.700155e+10
2004m2     A      0.03500   2.600118e+10
2004m2     B      0.02000   3.300333e+10
2004m2     C     -0.00500   4.500477e+11
2004m2     D      0.01100   1.800155e+10
2004m2     E     -0.02000   3.500288e+10
2004m2     F      0.01200   3.001109e+11
2004m2     G      0.04200   5.700442e+12
2004m2     H      0.01100   2.800888e+11
2004m2     I      0.01900   3.600115e+10
2004m2     J      0.00550   2.100333e+13
2004m2     K     -0.01500   5.001550e+10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`pandas.qcut()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.qcut.html) function:

```
In [1]: df['port'] = df.groupby(['date'])['marketcap'].transform(
                        lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 10, labels = False))

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
      date ticker  return     marketcap      port
0   2004m1      A  0.0250  2.500117e+10       0.0
1   2004m1      B  0.0400  3.600111e+10       3.0
2   2004m1      C -0.0150  4.900222e+11       7.0
3   2004m1      D -0.0250  1.400134e+10       0.0
4   2004m1      E -0.0400  3.200288e+10       1.0
5   2004m1      F -0.0120  9.300110e+10       5.0
6   2004m1      G  0.0350  5.500512e+12       8.0
7   2004m1      H  0.0460  2.100177e+11       6.0
8   2004m1      I  0.0050  3.300155e+10       2.0
9   2004m1      J  0.0075  2.400999e+13       9.0
10  2004m1      K  0.0250  7.700155e+10       4.0
11  2004m2      A  0.0350  2.600118e+10       0.0
12  2004m2      B  0.0200  3.300333e+10       1.0
13  2004m2      C -0.0050  4.500477e+11       7.0
14  2004m2      D  0.0110  1.800155e+10       0.0
15  2004m2      E -0.0200  3.500288e+10       2.0
16  2004m2      F  0.0120  3.001109e+11       6.0
17  2004m2      G  0.0420  5.700442e+12       8.0
18  2004m2      H  0.0110  2.800888e+11       5.0
19  2004m2      I  0.0190  3.600115e+10       3.0
20  2004m2      J  0.0055  2.100333e+13       9.0
21  2004m2      K -0.0150  5.001550e+10       4.0
```

Using your toy example in Stata:

```
clear

input str7 date str1 ticker return marketcap
"01/2004"     "A"      0.02500   2.500117e+10
"01/2004"     "B"      0.04000   3.600111e+10
"01/2004"     "C"     -0.01500   4.900222e+11
"01/2004"     "D"     -0.02500   1.400134e+10
"01/2004"     "E"     -0.04000   3.200288e+10
"01/2004"     "F"     -0.01200   9.300110e+10
"01/2004"     "G"      0.03500   5.500512e+12
"01/2004"     "H"      0.04600   2.100177e+11
"01/2004"     "I"      0.00500   3.300155e+10
"01/2004"     "J"      0.00750   2.400999e+13
"01/2004"     "K"      0.02500   7.700155e+10
"02/2004"     "A"      0.03500   2.600118e+10
"02/2004"     "B"      0.02000   3.300333e+10
"02/2004"     "C"     -0.00500   4.500477e+11
"02/2004"     "D"      0.01100   1.800155e+10
"02/2004"     "E"     -0.02000   3.500288e+10
"02/2004"     "F"      0.01200   3.001109e+11
"02/2004"     "G"      0.04200   5.700442e+12
"02/2004"     "H"      0.01100   2.800888e+11
"02/2004"     "I"      0.01900   3.600115e+10
"02/2004"     "J"      0.00550   2.100333e+13
"02/2004"     "K"     -0.01500   5.001550e+10
end
```

The command `egen` produces equivalent results:

```
egen port = xtile(marketcap), nquantiles(10) by(date)

list, sepby(date)

     +---------------------------------------------+
     |    date   ticker   return   market~p   port |
     |---------------------------------------------|
  1. | 01/2004        A     .025   2.50e+10      1 |
  2. | 01/2004        B      .04   3.60e+10      4 |
  3. | 01/2004        C    -.015   4.90e+11      8 |
  4. | 01/2004        D    -.025   1.40e+10      1 |
  5. | 01/2004        E     -.04   3.20e+10      2 |
  6. | 01/2004        F    -.012   9.30e+10      6 |
  7. | 01/2004        G     .035   5.50e+12      9 |
  8. | 01/2004        H     .046   2.10e+11      7 |
  9. | 01/2004        I     .005   3.30e+10      3 |
 10. | 01/2004        J    .0075   2.40e+13     10 |
 11. | 01/2004        K     .025   7.70e+10      5 |
     |---------------------------------------------|
 12. | 02/2004        A     .035   2.60e+10      1 |
 13. | 02/2004        B      .02   3.30e+10      2 |
 14. | 02/2004        C    -.005   4.50e+11      8 |
 15. | 02/2004        D     .011   1.80e+10      1 |
 16. | 02/2004        E     -.02   3.50e+10      3 |
 17. | 02/2004        F     .012   3.00e+11      7 |
 18. | 02/2004        G     .042   5.70e+12      9 |
 19. | 02/2004        H     .011   2.80e+11      6 |
 20. | 02/2004        I     .019   3.60e+10      4 |
 21. | 02/2004        J    .0055   2.10e+13     10 |
 22. | 02/2004        K    -.015   5.00e+10      5 |
     +---------------------------------------------+
```

The differences in the results are attributed to the fact that indexing starts with one in Stata.